# How to fix "File file /tmp/delta-table does not exist in Delta Lake?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, docker-compose, delta-lake

Hello dear programmers,

I am currently setting up Delta Lake with Apache Spark. For the spark worker and master I am using the image `docker.io/bitnami/spark:3`.

What I am trying to do is via my python application is creating a new table of type `delta` via the spark master/worker I setup. However when I try to save the table I get the following error: `File file:/tmp/delta-table/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.json does not exist`.

This might have something to do with the worker/master container not being able to access my local files however I am not sure how to fix this. I also looked into using HDFS but should I be running a separate server for this because it seems to be built into [Delta Lake](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-storage.html#hdfs) already?

The code of my applications looks as follows:

```
import pyspark
from delta import *

builder = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .master("spark://spark:7077") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.1.0") \

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()

data = spark.range(0, 5)
data.write.mode("overwrite").format("delta").save("/tmp/delta-table")

df = spark.read.format("delta").load("/tmp/delta-table")
df.show()
```

Comment: Did you ever figured it out and if so, would you mind sharing your solution?

Comment: Same problem here :( You never found a fix?